# How to use setSizePolicy for QAbstractScrollArea

Tags: python, qt, layout, pyqt5, scrollview

I am trying to use the [setSizePolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop) property of a [QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html). Using this feature with a [QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) or [QFrame](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html) works as expected. However, using this feature with a [QAbstractScrollArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html) the result is unexpected.

The following minimum working example demonstrates this behavior:

Arranged in two `Parent` widgets are on the left a layout of *QAbstractScrollArea* widgets and on the right a set of *QFrame* widgets. Each widget gets assigned an individual height and all widgets specify in the size policy to be fixed to the *sizeHint* return size, which is fixed to the aforementioned height.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys


class ASWidget(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea):
    def __init__(self, height, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)

        self._height = height
        self.setStyleSheet("background: red;")

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(100, self._height)


class NonASWidget(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, height, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)

        self._height = height
        self.setStyleSheet("background: red;")

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(100, self._height)


class ParentWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, classType, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setSpacing(1)

        sizes = [5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65]
        for i in sizes:
            layout.addWidget(classType(i))


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        w1 = ParentWidget(ASWidget, self)
        w2 = ParentWidget(NonASWidget, self)

        w2.move(110, 0)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    dialog = Dialog()
    dialog.show()

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The result of the code above is this screen shot:

[image: Screen shot of the minimum working example]

As you can see, the QAbstractScrollArea widgets on the left do not make use of the fixed size policy in contrast to the QFrame widgets on the right.

What is the reason behind this and how can I make use of the *setSizePolicy* feature with *QAbstractScrollArea* widgets?

Comment: What is the point of your issue? Also, have you considered the minimum size hint?

Comment: @musicamante I would like to overload the *sizeHint* of a widget which inherits from *QAbstractScrollArea* and explicitly set the size of the widget with it. Using *setFixedHeight* works fine, but I think the other approach is much cleaner (if it would work).

Comment: I understand what you want to do, and I didn't talk about the size hint, nor the fixed size, but the [`minimumSizeHint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumSizeHint-prop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When subclassing widgets (besides QWidget itself), it's important to remember that all existing Qt subclasses also set some default properties or reimplement methods, including the abstract ones.

The [`minimumSizeHint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumSizeHint-prop) is the *recommended* minimum size of the widget, and the layout will (almost) always respect that. The following paragraph is important:

> QLayout will never resize a widget to a size smaller than the minimum size hint unless minimumSize() is set or the size policy is set to QSizePolicy::Ignore. If minimumSize() is set, the minimum size hint will be ignored.

The minimum hint is important as it's valid only for widgets that are inside a layout, and it also can be used as a [sub]class "default" instead of using `minimumSize()`, which should be used for instances instead.

While many widgets return an invalid (as in *ignored*) minimum size hint, others don't, as it's important for their nature to have a default minimum size set. This happens for subclasses of QAbstractButton and for all subclasses of QAbstractScrollArea.

To override this behavior (while not suggested under a certain size), just overwrite the method. Note that it's preferred to have the `sizeHint()` return `minimumSizeHint()` and not the other way around, so that `sizeHint()` always respect the minimum hint, but can still be overridden in other subclasses.

```
class ASWidget(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea):
    def __init__(self, height, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)

        self._height = height
        self.setStyleSheet("background: red;")

    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.minimumSizeHint()

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(100, self._height)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. This definitely solves my issue. But wouldn't it be more "correct" to overload the *minimumSizeHint* method to return an invalid minimum size and use sizeHint for its intended purpose? If this suggestions makes any sense could you please also shed some light on that approach?

Comment: @Woltan It depends on what you plan to do with the widget, what's its purpose and what contents should it show. Considering that your was only an example, I don't know what you intend to do (for instance, you added the parent widgets without a main layout, which normally shouldn't be done), but if you do that the result is that without a valid minimum hint the widgets can become *too* small. For scroll areas, that's not a good idea, since the contents would become almost invisible and the scroll bars unusable. For complex widgets like those, you should always provide a *valid* minimum hint.

Comment: @musicamente You are right, my example does not show what I intend to use the widget for. In my case the widget does not have any scroll bars but is scrolled "externally" and the small size is sufficient for exactly that. From your comment I conclude, that it is ok to overload *minimumSizeHint* and that is what I am going to do right after accepting your answer. Thanks again for you help!